# Bounty Award Procedure may be Unclear

Tags: support, bounty

Actually, it was unclear, at least to me.  But perhaps it is perfectly clear to others.

Irrelevant background:

> A month ago, a user posted a question.  It was a little unclear (external link to video without summary of what was contained there, description didn't match prompted for information, and both contradicted the error message in the code).  Myself and others asked, in comments, to provide a summary of the video, and to clarify the problem ensuring code & error messages matched description.  After the cleanup, the question was worthy of a few up votes, and the user probably thought they were going to get a review.  I certainly was interested in answering, once the question was cleaned up, but didn't get around to it right then.  3 weeks went by, and I peeked at the question, and saw no one had posted any answers.  I still didn't have time to answer it, but felt they deserved one, so I slice off 50 of my own hard-earned reputation and started a bounty.

Of the resulting 3 answers, I felt two were good (together they'd be great); the third was a "Your implementation is really good", which it wasn't.  From [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), I see:

> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon **next to each answer** to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)

The "*click the bounty award icon next to each answer*" sounds like:

- I can select one answer, and it would get the full +50, or
- I could select 2 answers and they would get +25 each, and so on.

Since I thought the 2 answers together formed a good answer, awarding +25 each seemed perfect.  So I click the the award icon next to the first, got the "are you sure - you can't undo this" message, cancelled, went back to the help, reread it to be sure I was doing it right, returned to the question, clicked the award icon for one answer, said "yes", and the award icons vanished for all other answers.

This is not what I expected to happen.

Rereading the clause, yet again, I now see there are two pieces of information entwined in that sentence:

- Next to each answer, there is a bounty award icon.
- Click one of those bounty award icons to permanently award your bounty to the answerer.

Can we get the help information reworded to make that clearer?

Comment: Yeah that sentence is clearly ambiguous. You may want to post this on MSE. But given that "Meta requests don’t integrate with any existing ticketing system" and there are "thousands of accumulated bug reports and feature requests" I don't think this will happen for a long time, if at all. But then again I don't think [The Loop](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/) would be good for this either...

Comment: the best fix there would probably be replacing "each" with "an"

Comment: @Vogel612 yes that would probably fix it. Such a small grammatical edit seems like one of those things that could be "fast tracked" if such a thing exists. That would be easier than [fixing this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/394796/217285) and far easier than [doing this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324104/303080).